# Login being blocked by adblocker

Tags: javascript, web, adblock

I am wondering, because I got a website login script and it uses this command:

```
if(document.getElementById('linkreg'))
    document.getElementById('linkreg').onclick = function () 
    {
        ajaxSend(php_fileusr, 'susr='+texts['register'], adboxshow);
        objLogare.adLogInr();
        return false;
    };
```

Anyways, this function is triggered when the register for a new account (same thing for recovering account but different script). Anyways, some users weren't able to register because the window never popped up. I figured out that this is caused by the adblock extension. I am wondering if there is any way to replace the command `adboxshow`. Does anyone know any alternatives that work the same but won't be blocked?

Comment: So `adboxshow` is a function that calls `window.open()`, or...? It would help us to help you if you showed the code for `adboxshow`. You can use a CSS-based dialog that opens as part of the same page rather than trying to open a second window.

Comment: If I was an adblocker, and would see a function called `adboxshow`, I would certainly block that as well. Can’t you rename it to something more sensible? It does indeed sound as if you want to show an advertising box here…

Comment: Adblock is designed to block containers/scripts/css classes, that has "ad*" prefix. You should avoid that, even if it's short for "awsome dynamic" ;)

Comment: Oh ok. I'm very new to Javascript so I thought that it was a javaScript function not a user function. That makes more sense. Thanks I'll work on changing the names and see how it works. I'll let you guys know what happens/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments from Poke and Cezary, I figured it out

> If I was an adblocker, and would see a function called adboxshow, I
> would certainly block that as well. Can’t you rename it to something
> more sensible? It does indeed sound as if you want to show an
> advertising box here… – poke yesterday
>
> Adblock is designed to block containers/scripts/css classes, that has
> "ad*" prefix. You should avoid that, even if it's short for "awsome
> dynamic" ;) – Cezary Daniel Nowak yesterday

I changed every function, class, or div that had the word "ad" in it, specifically starting with the word "ad" in order to make it compliant with ad blocker.

-I hope this helps others who are trying to make a website that has legitimate content that is not blocked by adblockers.